# Behaviour subject not working properly in angular

Tags: angular

I am stuck with a problem in Angular. This is a login issue. I have created a service which have login and logout functions and a behaviour subject which is true and false based on login logout status.

Based on same behaviour subject I am displaying login and logout button.

But something is going wrong - after the first time login. Logout button comes and login hide but when I click on logout and login again this time login button not disappears and logout button remains hidden.

Below is stackblitz link of my code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nkg8cx

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and not a link to your site or any third party site.

Comment: as per my knowledge I have seen many  questions with same approach. it's not easy to write lines of code with multiple files here. btw thanks for your suggestions. Also I got my answer by following same approach

Comment: If everyone else jumped off a cliff, you would, too? The statement from the SO rule book is clear. Do not do that. Wherever you have seen it done, they just haven't been caught yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling

```
this.loginSubject.next(true)
```

before you're setting the local storage user

```
localStorage.setItem('loggedInUser',JSON.stringify(response));
```

in the login() function on the login service.

This means in this method in the header component

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.loginService.loginSubject.subscribe(res=>{    
      if(res){
        if(localStorage.getItem("loggedInUser")){
          this.showLogin = false
          this.loogedInUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("loggedInUser"))
        }
      }else{
        this.showLogin = true
      }
    })
  }
```

this check fails immediately after the subject is triggered because the local storage user isn't set yet

```
if(localStorage.getItem("loggedInUser")){
```